# Spread syntax gives error when copying react component properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spread-syntax

I'm using react and I'm trying to use the spread syntax. For some reason it doesn't work and it gives an error:

```
const { className, children, ...otherprops } = this.props;
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Unexpected token, and it points to the first dot

Comment: Have you fixed this ? how

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting `Unexpected token` because you are missing one babel preset, `stage-0`

[With stage-0, it works](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-0&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=let%20props%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20className%3A%20''%2C%0A%20%20children%3A%20'children'%2C%0A%20%20randomProp%3A'w'%2C%0A%20%20randomPropB%3A'ww'%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Aconst%20%7B%20className%2C%20children%2C%20...otherporps%20%7D%20%3D%20props%3B)

[Without stage-0, it doesn't work](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=let%20props%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20className%3A%20''%2C%0D%0A%20%20children%3A%20'children'%2C%0D%0A%20%20randomProp%3A'w'%2C%0D%0A%20%20randomPropB%3A'ww'%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20%7B%20className%2C%20children%2C%20...otherporps%20%7D%20%3D%20props%3B)

In order to add it, you have to

1º Install it

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-0
```

2º Add it to `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["react","es2015","stage-0"]
}
```

Comment: Have the same issue.I tried both the steps and still its showing the same error. I am using CoreUi react theme. Also tried state 2 still not fixed